# EC2 Security Group inbound rule not working as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I have an instance that hosts a mongodb service and I am trying to allow incoming traffic for port 27017 from an autoscaling group of instances. I am adding the security group (that has the AG instances) I want to access the specific instance, but I see it times out.

> Inbound rule:

[image]

I have tried allowing a specific address or 0.0.0.0 and it works. Only when I am specifying the security group id it doesn't work.

Any help on this highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you also have a Load Balancer, you would want three security groups:

- **ELB-SG:** Allow incoming web traffic as appropriate (eg 80, 443). Associate it with the Load Balancer.
- **App-SG:** Allow incoming traffic *from ELB-SG*. Associate it with the Auto Scaling Group, which will automatically assign it to the instances launched via Auto Scaling.
- **Mongo-SG:** Allow incoming traffic *from App-SG* on port 27017. Associate it with the instance running Mongo.

Basically, have the security groups *reference another Security Group* and they will automatically accept traffic from instances associate with that other security group.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, great detailed explanation. I was doing more or less the same but in the end the problem was that I was trying to access the instance using the public IP. If you reference another Security Group you need to access that instance from the *private IP*